# Solution to homogeneous linear second order differential equation with non constant coefficients has no local maximum that is greater than $0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to prove that the solution to second order ODE can't have local maximum that is greater than $0$.

$$x'' + p(t) x' + q(t) x = 0$$

If: $p(t)$, $q(t)$ are continous and $q(t) < 0$

That is a homogeneous linear equations of order $2$ with non constant coefficients.

Now, I did some examples of that type with a known one solution. When the coefficients are not constant, and one solution is known, it is easy to use reduction of order to compute the second solution. Here I thought aboud substituting $x$ with $e^z$ but I don't know if that works.

Comment: A differential equation has no local maximum greater than zero. That is correct. It also has no local maximum smaller than or equal to zero. That is also correct. In fact,  a differential equation has no local, global or any other type of maximum whatsoever.

Comment: I mean a solution to differential equation.

Comment: So please write what you mean.

Comment: I think the only answer got it right. You can check his answer if you are curious. @uniquesolution

Comment: Btw, why would ppl downvote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $x(t)$ attains a local maximum at $t=t_0$; namely $x'(t_0)=0,x''(t_0)\le0$. Let $t=t_0$ in the equation to see what will happen.

Comment: Ohh, I think I got it! Thank you.

Comment: We have: $x'' + q(t) x = 0$ and we know that $x'' \leq 0$. Then we have that $q(t) x \geq 0$ and we know that $q(t) < 0$. Then it must be true that: $x \leq 0$.

Comment: It is when $t = t_0$. Is that correct? @xpaul

Comment: @mathman12 You are right.

Comment: could you help me with one proof? I know a solution to one of that equations but I don't know the other one and I don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469258/prove-sup-t-in-0-2yt-xt-leq-0-006-when-x-sin-x-0-y

Comment: Ok. Give me some time.

Comment: Sure, thank you! Btw, cool avatar, love the pi movie.