# Prove: $\sup_{t \in (0,2)}|y(t) - x(t)| \leq 0,006$ if: $x'' + \sin x = 0$, $y'' + y = 0$ with: $x(0) = y(0) = \frac{1}{4}$ and $x'(0) = y'(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Nonlinear second order problem given by:
$$x'' + \sin x = 0$$
with initial conditions set as: $x(0) = \frac{1}{4}$ and $x'(0) = 0$ ,

can be estimated by:
$$y'' + y = 0$$
with initial conditions set as: $y(0) = x(0)$ and $y'(0) = x'(0)$ .

Prove that:
$$\sup_{t \in (0,2)}|y(t) - x(t)| \leq 0,006$$

I was told that there is a prove that involves an inequation of:
$$|\sin z - z| \leq 0,003$$
for: $|z| \leq \frac{1}{4}$ but I don't know how.

---

I know that general solution for $y'' + y = 0$ can be found by Power Series Method. It's equal to: $y = \alpha \cos x + \beta \sin x$.

Comment: That is hard tbh. Maybe Gronwall-inequality, but the second order derivative makes it hard. The $\lvert z \rvert$ comes from $y(t) = 0.25\cos(t)$, i.e. $\lvert y(t) \rvert \leq 0.25$. So somewhere, the term $\lvert \sin(y(t)) - y(t) \rvert$ appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a straightforward approach, apply the Grönwall theorem to the first order systems. Set
$$
d(t)=\pmatrix{x(t)-y(t)\\x'(t)-y'(t)}.
$$
Then
$$
\|d'(t)\|\le\|d(t)\|+|x-\sin(x)|\le \|d(t)\|+\frac1{6·4^3},~~~d(0)=0,
$$
as for $|x|<\sqrt6$ one has $|x-\sin(x)|\le\frac{|x|^3}6$.

By Grönwall this results in
$$
\|d(t)\|\le \frac1{3·2^7}(e^t-1)
$$
At $t=2$ this bound is $0.0166381$, not small enough.

---

More specialized, consider the Wronskian-like helper function
$$
h_a(t)=x(t)\cos(t-a)-x'(t)\sin(t-a).
$$
Its derivative is
$$
h_a'(t)=-\sin(t-a)(x(t)+x''(t))=-\sin(t-a)(x(t)-\sin(x(t)))
\\\implies |h_a'(t)|\le \frac1{3·128}
$$
so that
$$
|h_a(t)-h_a(0)|\le\frac{t}{384}\le\frac1{192}~~\text{ for }~~ t\le 2
$$
Now set $t=a$, $a\in[0,2]$, to get
$$
|x(a)-x(0)\cos(a)|=|x(a)-y(a)|\le\frac1{192}=0.00520...
$$

Comment: The upper bound equation is $u'=u+c$ with $u(0)=0$, which has the solution $u(t)+c=e^t(u(0)+c)$ which gives $u(t)=c(e^t-1)$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks.

Comment: Why is $x(0) cos(a) = y(a)$? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Because $y(a)=\frac14\cos(a)$ and $x(0)=\frac14$.